# Create array of key => value thanks to "helper" functions

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have an 2 dimensional array with this values :

```
  [
    'id' => 12,
    'title' => 'the title', //and a few other key => value

    ],
        [
    'id' => 13,
    'title' => 'the title 13', // and a few other key => value
    ],...
```

In the end, I need to have a multidimensional array only with **id and title**

> [ $item['id'] => $item['title'], ...]

Usually, I'm doing a simple foreach to achieve this, but I want to use php function now. I've done this, but is there a proper way to do this?

```
$list = array_combine(array_column($list_forms, 'id'), array_column($list_forms, 'title'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [**third** argumenf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php#refsect1-function.array-column-parameters) of `array_column` it is:

```
$list = array_column($list_forms, 'title', 'id');
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great ! Didn't pay attention to the third parameter in array_column